# Sed is truncating first character if it is starting with "v" while appending in file

Tags: linux, shell

I am stuck in one of my production code where I am trying to append some content at the start of file and if the content which I want to append is starting with "v" , its getting truncated.

Steps to reproduce:

```
$ cat text.txt
Kubernetes document
$ var1=version1
$ sed -e "s/^/\\${var1} /" text.txt
```

Output:

```
ersion1 Kubernetes document
```

Desired Output:

```
version1 Kubernetes document
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the backslash is wrong. Check this:

```
var1=version1
echo "s/^/\\${var1} /"
```

Your escaping leads to the following sed command:

```
s/^/\version1 /
```

`\v` is a special char: vertical tab, which is not visible on your terminal.

The simple solution is to not escape at all, it's simply not needed when interpolating variables into a double quoted string:

```
sed -e "s/^/\\${var1} /" text.txt
```